# DBX Databricks - installing private GitHub repositories on clusters in a workspace

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, git, aws-databricks, databricks-dbx

I'm running code on Databricks clusters remotely using DBX - so my current directory is built into a wheel and then installed on the remote Databricks cluster. I'm having an issue where a private GitHub repo that I installed via poetry locally is not able to be cloned on the cluster due to a lack of authentication in the cluster. Is there a way to either connect a Databricks workspace to a Github repository so that the remote clusters can clone the private repository, or provide authentication to the cluster some other way?